# Gwt editor that edit multiple propertys

Tags: google-maps, gwt, requestfactory, gwt-editors

Is it posible to create a proxy editor that edits multiple propertys ?

Here is an example that ilustrates what i want to do:

Supose i have an entity called Marker(like google maps) that haves two propertys  'LATITUDE' and 'LONGITUDE', so mi first touhgth would be to create a CompositeEditor composed by two sub-editors (DoubleBox from GWTBootstap that edit Doubles)....

But now i want to make a better front end app. So im usign google maps that enables you to put a marker on the map and use its latitude and longitude property to set it on the proxy.

How can i manage to do this ???   1 MAP editor that edits 2 Propertys (latitude and longitude).

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use a `LeafEditor<Marker>` and create a new `Marker` with the new coordinates, or you can possibly use two `SimpleValueEditor` subeditors that you manipulate from code in response to events on the map.